# How not to open a file twice in linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, system-calls, stat

I have a linked list with an fd and a string I used to open this file in each entry. I want to open and add files to this list only if this file is not already opened, because I open and parse this files and do not want to do it twice. My idea was to compare the filename with every single name in this list, but my program do it multiple times and one file in Linux can have multiple names (soft/hard links). I think it should not be so complicated, because its easy for the OS to check, whether I already used a inode or not, r?
I already tried to `open` the same file with and without `flock`, but I always get a new `fd`.

Comment: Use `stat()` to get the inode (and filesystem) number. Compare the inodes, not the filenames. Or, if you *do* want to compare filenames, use a hash table to make it (somewhat) more efficient.

Comment: ...and no, the OS isn't going to do this for you. The whole point of low-level interfaces is to provide maximally generic building blocks so someone else can build a higher-level interface on top of them. Making this kind of behavior automatic would restrict operation -- it would mean there'd be things you couldn't do -- so it would be contrary to "maximally generic".

Comment: Also use `readlink` to handle symlinks.

Comment: @Jester, that would be handled for you if you were looking at the resolved inode numbers, since you need to explicitly pass `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` to get the inode of the link itself.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: As for `flock`, it's purely advisory locking -- it doesn't change how `open` works, but gives you a way to tell if any other advisory locks on the same content exist.

Comment: Well, I thought about opening the files and check for the inode (my structure already contains space for the fstat-structure), but so I have to open and close this file shortly after this. I hoped the OS could do it, maybe with another flag in open. thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you successfully open a file use [`fstat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fstat.html) on the file. Check to see if the `st_ino` and `st_dev` of the [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) filed in by `fstat` have already been recorded in your linked list. If so then close the file descriptor and move on to the next file. Otherwise add the file descriptor, the file name and `st_ino` and `st_dev` values to the list.

You can instead use [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) to check before opening the file, but using `fstat` after will be slightly faster if the usual case is that file hasn't already been opened.

Comment: I believe if `st_nlink` is 1 on a normal file you don't need to do a search. There's no other hard links.

Comment: @Schwern There could be other symlinks to the file.

Comment: @Schwern I wouldn't trust the link count too much.

Comment: As pointed out on the duplicate [How to identify if two file diescriptors point to the same file](//stackoverflow.com/a/49943843), `fstat` has the advantage that it's immune to race conditions caused by renaming files between opens.  (Or between stat and open).  It lets you check two `fd`s for being the same file or not regardless of how you got them.

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, it's often useful to consider your data structures.  Change to a data structure which does not allow duplicates, such as a hash table.

Maintain a set of which data you've seen before.  I've used a [hash table](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) for this set.  As per [@RossRidge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34098363/14660), use the inode and device as the key.  This allows duplicates to be discovered in O(1) time.

Here is an example implementation.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static int get_fd(GHashTable *fds, const char *filename, int mode) {
    int fd;
    struct stat stat;
    int keysize = 33;
    char key[keysize];  /* Two 64 bit numbers as hex and a separator */

    /* Resolve any symlinks */
    char *real_filename = realpath(filename, NULL);
    if( real_filename == NULL ) {
        printf("%s could not be resolved.\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Open and stat */
    fd = open( real_filename, mode );
    if( fd < 0 ) {
        printf("Could not open %s: %s.\n", real_filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if( fstat(fd, &stat) != 0 ) {
        printf("Could not stat %s: %s.\n", real_filename, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make a key for tracking which data we've processed.
       This uses both the inode and the device it's on.
       It could be done more efficiently as a bit field.
     */
    snprintf(key, keysize, "%lx|%lx", (long int)stat.st_ino, (long int)stat.st_dev);

    /*  See if we've already processed that */
    if( g_hash_table_contains(fds, key) ) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        /* Note that we've processed it */
        g_hash_table_add(fds, key);
        return fd;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int mode = O_RDONLY;
    int fd;
    GHashTable *fds = g_hash_table_new(&g_str_hash, &g_str_equal);

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char *filename = argv[i];

        fd = get_fd(fds, filename, mode);
        if( fd == 0 ) {
            printf("%s has already been processed.\n", filename);
        }
        else if( fd < 0 ) {
            printf("%s could not be processed.\n", filename);
        }
        else {
            printf("%s: %d\n", filename, fd);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a sample result.

```
$ touch one two three
$ ln one one_link
$ ln -s two two_sym
$ ./test one* two* three*
one: 3
one_link has already been processed.
two: 5
two_sym has already been processed.
three: 7
```

Comment: Actually, the OP should use a hash or tree for the FSid/inode file ID, rather than name.  Besides symlinks, there are bind mounts, hardlinks, and maybe other things.  But you're right that a linked list is a bad choice.

Comment: A file can have multiple names so a hash table is entirely useless and the problem is Linux-specific.

Comment: @sivizius Why is the problem "Linux" specific? Do you mean Unix? Either way, a combination of Ross' answer to determine the uniqueness of the data combined with my answer to use a table or tree to quickly search that data should produce an answer that's both correct and fast.

Comment: @sivizius I've completely reworked the answer, I misunderstood what you were looking for.  It still uses a hash table to make the duplicate search fast, and it also takes into account Ross's answer and Peter's comment about the key.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you don't close the successfully and intentionally opened files, you can use nonblocking `flock` to prevent another lock on the same file:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

int openAndLock(const char* fn){
  int fd = -1;
  if(((fd = open(fn, O_RDONLY)) >= 0) && (flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) == 0)){
      fprintf(stderr, "Successfully opened and locked %s\n", fn);
      return fd;
  }else{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open or lock %s\n", fn);
    close(fd);
    return -1;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
    openAndLock(argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
$ touch foo
$ ln foo bar
$ ./a.out foo foo
Successfully opened and locked foo
Failed to open or lock foo
$ ./a.out foo bar
Successfully opened and locked foo
Failed to open or lock bar
```

Comment: I already tried to open the same file with and without flock, but I always get a new fd.

Comment: @sivizius Have you tried this program? It works for me.

Comment: @sivizius Another `open`  flocked file should succeed and give you another filedescriptor. `Flock`ing that new filedescriptor should fail (until the old file lock is released).

Comment: i tried something similar with the same operation-const in assembly and I get different fd's, so: yes.

Comment: @sivizius If you wanted to prevent another `open` from succeeding, you'd need to use mandatory locking, which is expensive and requires filesystem support turned on. Without it, there's no way to prevent another `open` (but you can prevent another `open`+`flock` pair). Doing `open`+`flock` is essentially the same as having an inode table and checking it. The difference is with `flock`, it's the OS that maintains the table instead of you.

Comment: @PSkocik Using flock as a surrogate inode table is clever, but it's very rude to any other processes which need those files. This process will retain an exclusive lock on *all the files* while it's running, but it doesn't really need those locks. Other processes which need those files, and which check for a lock, will block and it could become a serious performance problem.